# Can I use a single AAA battery to power a motor?

Tags: stepper-motor, batteries

Can I use a single AAA battery which has 1.5V and 700mAh to run a stepper motor which has operating voltage 3.1V and draws 1.2A/phase?

If, yes then how many minutes will it run?

Someone briefly explain if possible.

Comment: No.  ESR of battery to DCR of stepper is not low enough and mWh  capacity may be too little. Computed in mWs

Comment: You took the 'briefly' part to heart:D 1.2A/phase is quite a big stepper to hold with an AAA cell, in effects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but there are efficiency issues so it's not exactly easy to determine the runtime.

You need to use a step up (boost) power converter. It will take your 1.5V and with some electromagnetic work transform it in 3.1V or whatever (there are limitation but this is feasible).

Now, the available *power* doesn't change (to be picky we are talking about *energy* but it scales), so if you have 700mAh at 1.5V and boost it up to 3.1V (to simplify the calculation) you'll have about 340mAh available.

Also the converter to work need to use some of that power. A good starting point is 80% of efficiency (depends on many thing). So you are left with 0.27Ah available for your motor.

Ignoring other losses (motor controlles and other circuit parts) you need to determine your actual load: a stepper without microstepping always drives one or two phases, depending on the drive mode. Assuming half-stepping in average you are driving 1.5 phases, so you sink 1.8A; with 0.27Ah this should be about 9 minutes (unless I flunked some calculation)

There's another big thing to handle: your battery is 700mAh but the *effective* capacity depends on the current actually sinked from the battery (it depends on the battery technology). So even if *theorically* it should handle 700mA for 1 hour or 350mA for 2 hours, it's quite probable that in the second case it will last longer.

In the end, it depends on how the 700mAh rating was determined, if with a constant sink or some standard power profile: many consumer batteries are rated with the 'digital camera' profile, with a relatively low constant load and only some high current pulses.

So, it's difficult to answer, you'll need some testing. I'd recommend to acquire an evaluation board for your booster of choice and work from that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot power a stepper motor with an operating voltage of 3.1V with 1.5V.

Also, the power consumption of a stepper motor depends on its operating conditions.  The current that you specified (1.2A) is probably the peak current specification.  Therefore, the "how long" question cannot be adequately answered with the information provided.

Comment: Well, the phase current is nominal for the holding torque… when driving steppers you set the current on the phase (unless they are cheap unipolars) and they develop the corresponding torque. Anyway yes, it's extremely dependant on the load and on the use case

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at power. You say the motor needs 3.1V and 1.2A per phase. I am not sure how to parse that exactly, but to get a rough idea, let's just say it is 3.1V RMS and 1.2A RMS per phase. That means the total power is 3.1 * 1.2 * sqrt(3) = 6.4 Watts.

That is probably not exactly the right equation. But it should be ballpark. Maybe the real power is 2 Watts or 15 Watts. In any event, it is not reasonable to try to get 2 Watts out of an AAA battery. You say it is a 700mAh, 1.5V battery. I think that means it is an alkaline battery. I know from experience if you try to take 2 Watts from an AAA alkaline battery, you will not get 1.5V. You will be lucky to get 1V. The battery may make the motor move briefly, but it will not even run for 1 minute.

And we are ignoring another big problem. You will need to boost the voltage up to 3.1V somehow. Boosting from a single AAA alkaline battery is very challenging under heavy load, because the input voltage will drop a lot. Your regulator will need to run with Vin as low as 0.8 or 0.7V. This is just very, very challenging.